# Xml structure with XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have class:

```
public class EnglishWord implements Serializable, Comparable,
        Cloneable {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EnglishWord.class);
```

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5832989302176618764L;
private String word;// in lowercase if not personal name
private int occurenceNumber = 1;// 0,1,2,3,
private int rating;// 1-first, 2 - second...
private Set<String> builtFrom;
private String translation;
private boolean isVerb;
private boolean isNoun;
private boolean isIrregular;
```

....
}

I have Set words = new TreeSet();
And I use XStream for serialization:

```
XStream xs = new XStream();
xs.alias("englishWord", EnglishWord.class);
FileOutputStream fs = null;
try {
  fs = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
xs.toXML(words, fs);
try {
  fs.flush();
  fs.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

After this I get structure of file like this:

```
   
     <englishWord>
       <word >the </word >
       <occurenceNumber >7480 </occurenceNumber >
       <rating >1 </rating >
       <builtFrom class="tree-set" >
         <no-comparator/ >
         <string >The </string >
         <string >the </string >
       </builtFrom >
       <isVerb >false </isVerb >
       <isNoun >false </isNoun >
       <isIrregular >false </isIrregular >
     </englishWord>
```

Can I get something like this with XStream:

```
     <englishWord word="the" occurenceNumber="7480" rating="1" isVerb="true">
       <builtFrom class="tree-set" >
         <no-comparator/ >
         <string >The </string >
         <string >the </string >
       </builtFrom >
      </englishWord >
```

???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert them to attributes try the following:

```
xs.useAttributeFor(EnglishWord.class, "word");
xs.useAttributeFor(EnglishWord.class, "occurenceNumber");
xs.useAttributeFor(EnglishWord.class, "rating");
xs.useAttributeFor(EnglishWord.class, "isVerb");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Look at the [Alias Tutorial](http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html) and you want the Attribute Alias section.